# Strange sharepoint error at UserProfile Application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

this is a new sharepoint installation, and I have this problem when I navigate to the newly installed site.

Any help please

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions of application pool account and UPA account. Note that UPA permissions may be configured in two places in Central Admin: one under "administrators" and other under "permissions" while configuring UPA.

Also you should check timeout values in web.config located in same directory as UPA wcf service. Use IIS Manager to find it and try to increase timeout. I have had similar issue while SharePoint was hosted on slow machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your User Profile service application is corrupt. Delete and recreate UPSA.

Comment: I tried, but when I did, I got this error. This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.  I checked and all sites are UP in IIS.